# Batch Script to extract lines Between two given words

Tags: batch-file, match

I need to extract texts between two given words from a file.

### The File format is as below :

```
some lines
<name>text1</name>
some lines
some lines 
<name>text2</name>
some lines
<name>text3</name>
some more lines
```

- I need to extract all the occurrences of texts that occur between each of the name tags

  ```
  <name> extract this text here </name>
  ```

### Expected Output for above file :

- text1
- text2
- text3

Thank you.

Comment: I suggest batch files are not the right tool. This is a general truth.

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a free coding website... Show what you have done already and ask specific questions!

Answer (score 1):

This should work for the sample data provided:

```
for /f "tokens=2 delims=<>" %A in ('type test.txt ^| findstr "<name>"') do @echo %A
```

If using this inside of a batch script, be sure to change `%A` to `%%A`. Basically, this will run through lines containing `<name>`, and split the line by `<` and `>` characters using `delims=<>`, giving you `name`, `text in between`, `/name`. The `tokens=2` sets `%A` to only the second string.

Keep in mind this won't work if you have anything on the line before `<name>`. That would probably complicate things a lot more in batch, and I would then suggest using some parsing library in another language for that.

Also, this will not work if the text you wanted to extract contains `<` or `>`.

Comment: Hi tyeberius, Thank you for this. As you mentioned this works perfectly for the above format. However turns out my file have some leading spaces before <name> and probably is the reason why it doesn't work on the actual file.

Answer (score 0):

The following script extracts the text in between the desired tags of the file(s) provided as command line argument(s):

```dos
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

rem // Resolve command line arguments:
for %%F in (%*) do (
    rem // Read a single line of text following certain criteria:
    for /F "delims=" %%L in ('
        findstr /R "^[^<>]*<name>[^<>][^<>]*</name>[^<>]*$" "%%~F"
    ') do (
        set "LINE=%%L"
        rem /* Extract the desired string portion;
        rem    the preceding `_` is inserted for the first token
        rem    never to appear empty to the `for /F` loop: */
        setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
        for /F "tokens=3 delims=<>" %%K in ("_!LINE!") do (
            endlocal
            rem // Return found string portion:
            echo(%%K
        )
    )
)

endlocal
exit /B
```

This works only if there is exactly one tag `<name>`, followed by some text not containing `<` and `>` on its own, followed by exactly one tag `</name>`; this string must be on a single line and may be preceded or followed by some texts not containing `<` and `>` on their own.

Answer (score -1):

Suppose the input file is input.txt.

This should work :

```
grep '<name>.*</name>' input.txt | sed -r 's/<name>(.*)<\/name>/\1/'
```

grep finds the lines
sed deletes the name tags

Comment: `batch-file` not `bash`, completely different thing.